# Ruby render another controller partial

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have a controller and in the index view i am trying to render a partial from another controller.  Here is the other controller:

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController
def view 
    @model = Model.where('equipment_id' => params[:equipment_id])
    render :partial => 'view_model'

end
end
```

And in the index view I am trying this:

```
<div id ="mdl-inner_box" class="inner_box">
<%= render "model/view", :@model => Model.first %>
</div>
```

And my partial view is this:

```
<% @model.each do |m| %>
<div> <%= m.name %> </div>
<% end %>
```

I am getting this error:

ActionView::MissingTemplate at /equipment

Missing partial model/view with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :b

What is the correct way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are too many errors to really address this question!

First of all if you are showing code for your index action, why is it the view action?

> I have a controller and in the index view...

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController
  def view

  # should be

  def index
```

In your index view, presumably `app/views/models/index.html.erb` you render a partial, which points to `app/views/model/_view.html.erb`. That should probably be `models`

```
<%= render "model/view", :@model => Model.first %>

<!-- should be -->

<%= render "models/view", :model => @model %>
```

And set `@model` in your controller. You can put `Model.first` into the view itself, but I think that breaks MVC pattern a little bit.

Finally in the partial, you access the class variable `@model` defeating the purpose of passing it as a local. You also call `.each` on it, which is a method for looping through collections, not for individual records. For example you would do `@models.each` and never `@model.each`.

```
<% @model.each do |m| %>
  <div><%= m.name %></div>
<% end %>

<!-- should be something like -->

<%= model.name %>
```

---

Long story short, seems to me you're pretty lost, so I would start with a good book about Ruby on Rails before you continue. Here's a free one: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0